# `docker-compose` force run old image

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, raspberry-pi

I was running the very good [Linux Server IO Unifi Controller Docker image](https://docs.linuxserver.io/images/docker-unifi-controller) on my Raspberry Pi 3.

Unfortunately, this image no longer supports ARM32 since 2022-06-01.

I didn't realise this when I ran `docker-compose pull` to update to the latest image and now my controller won't work with the error message:

```
unifi-controller    |     ********************************************************
unifi-controller    |     ********************************************************
unifi-controller    |     *                                                      *
unifi-controller    |     *                         !!!!                         *
unifi-controller    |     *     This Unifi-Controller image does not support     *
unifi-controller    |     *        32 bit ARM due to a lack of OS packages       *
unifi-controller    |     *                                                      *
unifi-controller    |     *                                                      *
unifi-controller    |     ********************************************************
unifi-controller    |     ********************************************************
```

Is there any way to pin docker-compose back to the pre-deprecation version?

When I run `docker image ls`, I still have the following images available on my system:

```
REPOSITORY                             TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller   latest    deeabba24529   10 days ago     102MB
lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller   <none>    048ec856c236   9 months ago    524MB
lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller   <none>    4858fc11dcf2   10 months ago   520MB
```

Or I could adjust the version in `docker-compose.yml` to select an old version perhaps.

I understand the risks of running old software but the newer 64 bit Raspberry Pi 4s are out of stock in my country so immediate ability to upgrade hardware is limited and I need access to my network configuration.

Comment: You could re-tag a local version but the best option would be to pull a specific version of the image that is compatible with your architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `image:` configuration for the relevant containers in your `docker-compose.yaml` to a specific version, e.g:

```
image: lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller:latest
```

Use something like:

```
image: lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller:arm32v7-7.3.76
```

Or whichever version is appropriate. Using the `latest` tag is often considered an anti-pattern for exacly this reason -- upgrades to a new major version can break your application stack. In most cases it's better to pin your docker-compose.yml to a specific version.

Most image repositories have a browseable interface for discovering available tags. I'm not familiar with the `lscr.io` repository, but if there's not a convenient web interface you can use [`skopeo`](https://github.com/containers/skopeo):

```
skopeo list-tags docker://lscr.io/linuxserver/unifi-controller
```

Comment: Thanks, very useful (especially your pointers to the skopeo tool). For the Unifi controller are many images available and any recent ones tagged with arm32v7 are still deprecated. I ended up renaming my last known working on disk image with `docker tag 048ec856c236 arm32-working` then chaging the image line in docker-compose.yaml to `image: arm32-working`. A bit hacky but works well enough until I can upgrade the Pi